# Autosizable шрифт в textView

Tags: objective-c, textview

Как сделать изменяющийся шрифт в textView?

У меня есть постоянного размера rect для textView, при вводе нескольких строк текста размер шрифта должен меняться, чтобы вместить весь текст.

[скриншот](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/12010854/2.png)
(Сверху UILable, ниже UITextView)

Как видно, в `TextView` текст неправильно размещается, пробовал подгонять, используя значение `conteinerSize.height`, но он неправильные числа показывает.

```
NSString*ourText = [self.textField.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];

UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Marker Felt" size:470];

int i;
for(i = 470; i > 10; i=i-20)
{
    font = [font fontWithSize:i];

    CGSize constraintSize = CGSizeMake(200.0f, MAXFLOAT);

    CGSize textSize = [ourText sizeWithFont:font constrainedToSize:constraintSize lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];

    if(textSize.height <= 160.0f)
        break;
}

self.textView.font=font;
self.textView.text=ourText;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[self.textField  setAdjustsFontSizeToFitWidth:YES] не подходит?
Просто UITextView со скролом, ему как бы не надо.

**UPD**

нагуглил такую вот [категорию](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1095550/887325) но поизучав увидел что категория `NSString(UIStringDrawing)` почти полностью депрекейтед после iOS7.0, которая используется выше. Поэтому Вам придется поизучать этот вопрос в принципе идея ясна. Как решите траблу буду рад Вашему решению, будет время сам выложу.

**UPD**

Пришла в голову еще одна идея вот [проджек](http://cl.ly/2T0307060g3r) где я реализовал ее.

Comment: Так в textField только одна строка.(  Так, конечно, подошел бы.

Comment: Поизучал тему, обновил ответ.

Comment: Спасибо, за идею, хороший рабочий вариант, только до ума довести надо.

Comment: Ага, ну, думаю, там Ваших сил хватит.